# Unable to log output in new android studio

Tags: android, console

I am new to `Android Studio`. I successfully created a `Hello World` app from the example in Android website. Now, I want to play around by using some statement to print in the `logcat` but it doesn't works. Below is my `ApplicationTest.java` code:

```
package com.example.abc.myloggingapplication;

import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;
import android.util.Log;

/**
  * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing   Fundamentals</a>
 */
  public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
       public ApplicationTest() {

       super(Application.class);
       Log.d("MyTest", "Here goes the output!"); // THIS IS THE NEW STATEMENT INSERTED BUT PRINTS NOTHING IN CONSOLE LOG IN ANDROID STUDIO SDK.
    }
 }
```

Other files are same as provided by the `Hello World` example in Android website. In `Android Studio` sdk, I entered the logcat to `debug` but still no luck. Can anybody point me out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Do you actually create an instance of the class ApplicationTest? Otherwise the constructor is never called and thus is the output not logged.

Comment: Hi @user2481422, `Log.d` goes to LogCat, not to console. (Just to make sure you are looking at the right place).

Comment: @AuroMetal yes I edited the question. I meant logcat. Sorry I am new to android.

Comment: it appears when i do this? you are sure you are running the test, not your normal application?

Comment: @ColinGillespie could you elaborate? I am just clicking the run button and using the emulator. The app opens in the emulator and I check the messages in the `logcat`.

Comment: @user2481422 this code does not run when you are running your app. This is apart of the test suite. It is entirely independent of your app. If you look at your run configurations there may be an entry for running your test.

Comment: @ColinGillespie ok I ran my `ApplicationTest.java` by right clicking it but still doesn't shows up.

Comment: @user2481422, another quick note: On the Logcat, make sure the LogLevel and Filter are correct. I believe the Log level is set to `Verbose`, set it to `Debug` and perhaps set the Filter to `No Filters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your logcat:
Check View -> Tool windows -> Android Monitor.
Or Alt + 6

If that doesnt help, make sure you have an instance of your class. Otherwise the constructor is never called and therefor the log.d is never called.

Edit:

As other's have stated: Check if you are running the Test Application, if you want to do so. Otherwise make sure you code in your actual application and not your test application.

Comment: Hmm, I understood. I wrote it in `MainActivity.java` file and it worked! I was writing in the test file.